# Highlight unvalid fields instead of prompting towards a Error Page at wordpress comments

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, comments

I have a huge problem. I used the comments.php from "EmptyCanvas". Code of it can be seen here: http://pastebin.com/YHDy2q4a However, it prompts me towards an error page when I do not fill out the fields as required when posting a comment. I'd rather like a highlighting of fields, which I use with CF7 Forms. Code of it can be seen here: http://pastebin.com/uFgf07JB

I googled for it, and got redirected to another question which was not making things clear for me.

Thanks for any help, Shawn

PS: Tried a few ways, including [this](http://www.9bitstudios.com/2013/04/add-additional-comment-form-validation-in-wordpress/). However, I keep getting prompted towards my error page. :/

Comment: you have to use javascript instead of PHP for the comment section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i mentioned above on comment section you have to use `javascript` or `jquery` to validate your comment form on the same page without redirecting it to somewhere else.

Here is a nice tutorial to **validate your comment form with jquery**:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/adding-form-validation-to-wordpress-comments-using-jquery/

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I tried using this approach, but it seems that somehow, something in my comments.php is prompting me towards the error page. However, I can't find what it is. I can't change too much of the comments.php base structure, though. :/

Comment: @ShawnWhite you don't have to change too much, just have to implement the jquery validation code, but for displaying the errors on correct position, error color etc. you have to add some extra css.

Comment: Thanks, I made it. Great tutorial!